# Unable to use categoryBitMask to assign SCNLight lights to particular SceneKit nodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I'm trying to use `categoryBitMask` in SceneKit to make it so certain `SCNLight` lights only affect certain object nodes.

The documentation seems simple enough, but I can't get things to work properly.

For example, here's my light:

```
SCNLight *lightFront = [SCNLight light];
lightFront.color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.90f alpha:1.0f];
lightFront.type = SCNLightTypeOmni;
lightFront.castsShadow = YES;
lightFront.categoryBitMask = 2;
```

And here's my object node:

```
characterNode = [SCNNode node];
SCNScene *characterScene = [SCNScene sceneWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"character_idle" withExtension:@"dae"] options:nil error:nil];
for( SCNNode *node in characterScene.rootNode.childNodes ) {
    node.categoryBitMask = 2;
    [characterNode addChildNode:node];
}
characterNode.categoryBitMask = 2;
```

The `categoryBitMask` in both cases match. But! `lightFront` does not affect the characterNode.

If I change the light's `categoryBitMask` to 3, though, the node does show the light:

```
lightFront.categoryBitMask = 3;
```

This should work the opposite, right?

Other object nodes in the scene -- even those with different `categoryBitMasks` -- all seem to get the same lighting effects. Meaning, `lightFront` above will be visible or invisible on *all* object nodes in my scene, regardless of `categoryBitMask`. As far as I can tell.

Help!

Comment: I am not sure of this, but I think you the problem might be because you are using int instead of bits.

Try replacing 1 by `0b1`, 2 by `0b10`, 3 by `0b11` etc.

It's probably not the cause of your problem, but it wil at least remove one possible source of confusion.

Comment: Your for loop copies all the characterScene.rootNode.childNodes into characterNode but it is never added to the scene…?

Comment: I didn't include all of the code, just what I thought were the relevant bits.

Comment: note that `2 & 3 != 0` and so setting `2` or `3` for your light's *bit mask* should lead to the same result.

Comment: @mnuages: Weird, though, that is actually changes the effect, though. It's different!

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same problem, using interface builder and category mask therein, have experimented with different combinations but to no avail. On using @Moustach 's solution, node itself becomes invisible.

Comment: I got it, it was in Attenuation property wherein I was supposed to change category bitmask in a lightNode. Thanks.